# How do I use Predef.implicitly from a Scala macros?

Tags: scala, macros, implicit, scala-2.10

There is a method with this signature that creates implicit parameter behind the scene:

```
class A {
    def test[T: ClassTag](t: T) = println(t)
}
val a = new A
a.test(123456)
```

So the implicit parameter should be provided to the call of method `test`. When I do the reify in REPL, call tree looks like this:

```
Apply(
    Apply(
        Select(
            Select(
                newTermName("a"), 
                newTermName("test")
            ), 
        List(
            Literal(Constant(123456))) // explicit method args
        ), 
    List(
        Select(This(newTypeName("Predef")),
        newTermName("implicitly"))) // implicit args
    )
)
```

I'm trying to make this call using macro implementation but this doesn't compile and gives me: Predef is not an enclosing class. I tried different things without success and didn't found any sample on this.

So the question is: **how to provide implicit argument to method using macro?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Manual AST manipulation can be tricky. Try `Select(Ident(newTermName("scala")), newTermName("Predef"))` instead of `This(newTypeName("Predef"))`.

Or even better, consider using quasiquotes (http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/macros/quasiquotes.html). With them, composing a reference to implicitly becomes as simple as `scala.Predef.implicitly`.

Comment: Thanks, that's works. I know about quasiquotes but trying to minimize dependencies and understand more deeply what's happening. All this macro stuff is great. Thanks!